# Use htaccess to only allow download of files if user agent is a specific type

Tags: .htaccess, user-agent

I have a folder with some zip files in it. I want to reject all requests to download them directly unless the user agent is of the type I specify (eg. user-agent : `myuseragent`)

How is this possible with .htaccess file?

Rejected requests would redirect to the index file while accepted requests will download the file.

eg. if a user tried http://download.com/files/myfile.zip they would get rejected but if a script with a useragent of 'myuseragent' access the same url, it would download the file

I understand that useragents can be spoofed. It is only mild protection from having the files freely available

Comment: Please provide an example of such download URL.

Comment: Be aware that it is possible to fake `user-agent`. For example, `curl -A` and `wget -U` do that. In Safari, if you enable the Develop menu then you can select your own user agent. In Firefox, use `about:config`.

Answer (score 2):

Here how you can do it using **.htaccess and mod_rewrite**:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !=myuseragent
RewriteRule ^files/.*$ - [F,L]
```

The above rule will instruct Apache to issue 403 Access Denied response for any file in `/files/` folder if user agent is not equal to `myuseragent`.

If you want to issue 404 File Not Found response, replace `[F,L]` by `[R=404,L]`.

If you want to redirect such failed requests to home page then use this rule (you can change redirect from 302 to whatever other redirect code you like):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} !=myuseragent
RewriteRule ^files/.*$ / [R=302,L]
```

Comment: I put this in a .htaccess file in the folder called /files/ and it allowed downloads of any file from any useragent

Comment: The rule was supposed to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed in `/files/.htaccess`, then you have to alter a rule a bit -- remove `files/` part and put full domain name instead of `/` . It is also depends how you wrote your user agent string -- does it contains spaces, case sensitive? Please provide what have you done exactly (in case if the above corrections will not work).